# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at init.e.fn.valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, shim, unbounce

Sample Code snippet

```
 var joinedArr = ["first choice", "second choice"];
 $(joinedArr).valid();
```

The above code is throwing me *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at init.e.fn.valid (https://builder-assets.unbounce.com/published-js/jquery-shims.bundle-deb76da.z.js:1:4815) at :1:14* Error

I am trying the stuff in **unbounce**

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle code to test what is causing the issue.

Comment: this is in unbounce, I have a form for which I have used some script to achieve multistep form. It was working until unbounce did some updates.

Comment: Do you have documentation link for the valid method? I am not able to see anything on that.

Comment: http://unbouncepages.com/test-form-script-error/ 
here I tried to replicate the issue, you can check in the console.  While debugging I got to the point where 
``` return lp.jQuery(validateArr.join()).valid();
```
which was actually stopping the script from executing